# Pronoun position with infinitive

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots, infinitif

"I decided not to do it."

Since "to do" is an infinitive, we have to put the verb (*faire*) after *ne pas*. Should we also put the pronoun (*le*) after *ne pas* or before *pas*?

> J'ai décidé de ne pas **le** faire.
>
> J'ai décidé de ne **le** pas faire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one used to be the norm until the end of the 18th century but would be extremely literary today.

> *Votre père m'avait priée **de ne le pas faire**; mais, puisque ses précautions sont inutiles, et que la Nature vous en a déjà tant appris, je vous dirai qu'en effet il y a au monde un certain peuple agréable, insinuant, dont les manières sont tout à fait douces, qui ne songe qu'à nous plaire, et nous plaît aussi.* (*Les Amours de Psyché et Cupidon* - Jean de la Fontaine - 1669)
>
> *Je conclus donc qu'il était juste, sans péril, nécessaire, de la faire chef de ce conseil, et très-dommageable et même dangereux **de ne le pas faire**, mais que je croyais aussi qu'il n'était pas moins à propos **de ne lui pas tellement abandonner** ce conseil qu'il en devint une chimère, et que le comte se rendît maître de la marine;…* (*Les Mondes* - Fontenelle - 1686)

The first one is what started to be commonly used since around 1830 and definitely the current standard.

Note that the old form is still present in set expressions like:

> *C'est à n'en plus finir* (vs *c'est à ne plus en finir*)

Answer (score 0):

The second one does not work any more - as jiliagre says - it does sound very old. The first one is correct nowadays.